# Vuex Better way to Map?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm just starting to learn Vuex and currently using modules. Is there better way to `mapState`, `mapMutations`, `mapActions`, `mapGetters` than this?

```
    ...mapActions('FootageModal', ['setElements', 'setActiveFootage']),
    ...mapActions('Scene', ['addScene', 'deleteScene']),
    ...mapMutations('Content', ['resetActiveContent']),
    ...mapGetters({
      getSceneStatus: 'Scene/getStatus',
      getStatus: 'getStatus'
    }),
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you use `mapGetters` is good. You can do the same for the rest:

```js
...mapActions({
      someAction: 'someAction',
      footageModal: 'FootageModal'
})
```

```js
...mapMutations({
    someMutation: 'SET_SOME_MUTATION'
}),
```

Also worth noting. You should add `mapGetters` and `mapState` as computed properties, and `mapActions` and `mapMutations` as methods.

Comment: your `mapActions` example doesn't match the OP's intent. OP is mapping two actions from `FootageModal` module. You mapped one action named "FootageModal". These are not equivalent.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for commenting. 
  `...mapAction({ footageModal: 'FootageModal'})`, is this going to get all `Actions` in `FootageModal` module?

Comment: @user3779015, No, `...mapAction({ footageModal: 'FootageModal'})` will look for an action called 'FootageModal' in the root namespace. If not found, it will fail.